# git revert commit, back to staged and unstaged

Tags: git, git-commit

I regularly use

```
git add -p
```

to select which parts I want to commit. Once I selected what I wanted; I proceed to using

```
git commit -a
```

and finalize my commit. Now I realize that I **should NOT have used the -a option**, because now I have undone the work done with `git add -p` (that is, splitting my changes in multiple commits).

The only way I know to revert this, and make it back the way I wanted is:

```
git reset HEAD~
git add -p
git commit
```

Is there any way that I **don't** have to do `git add -p` again; performing the exact same operations to split my changes into multiple commits? So I want to undo the `git commit -a` and go back to the staged and unstaged files just before (that is **the way git status was just after using git add -p**).

Answer (score 1):

To recover files or code that was lost due to a mistaken commit, you can look at the dangling blobs.  To do this, run:

```
$ git fsck --unreachable
```

This gives you a list of the dangling blobs ... for example:

```
unreachable blob 070204aa62dc0ef612f922a02d06d3....
unreachable blob 821c4ca73cb5c99f7fa5f23358e3a9....
unreachable blob b91c74fc1b5c0f8eb8ccfd1a8024c6....
```

You then check out one of those blobs to check for your missing code:

```
git show 070204aa62dc0ef612f922a02d06d3....
```

This lets you view the content in the dangling blob, but does not give you the name of the file. You can then write that content to a file by using the first 5 characters of the sha1

```
git show d06d3 > myfile
```

This puts 'myfile' in the directory you are currently in. Myfile at this point is a .txt which you can then copy and paste/convert to the correct MIME type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does, but it won't return me to the part where I had **staged** and **unstaged** files; it will only give me back all the files as **staged**...

Comment: If the goal is recovery, checking for dangling blobs is a good solution. This lets you go back to a  point in time before you made your mistake.  Use $ git fsck --unreachable

Comment: I think there might be something there... I see unreachable blobs and they might contain what I need; however it is difficult to know which one...

Comment: you can at least change your answer to this partial answer; it is a hint along the way. The answer you have now really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: No worries, now I have a clear idea of whats gone wrong, I've given a clear step by step solution which I hope helps you.

Comment: this does help; although there are many steps involved; I need to check all blobs manually, put aside my total changes; apply the partial changes from the correct blobs,...

Comment: Thats the only problem with this approach unfortunately.  You can't pinpoint the files :(  But if you get the code back it will be worth your time

Comment: I didn't lose any work; I lost the fact that I started splitting up my work in multiple commits... so it depends whether that is worth the effort...